# How to change shortcut for iTerm2 clear lines?

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

`Ctrl + l` is the default shortcut for clear lines in iTerm2, I want to change it to `Cmd + l`, but can't find this action:

[image]

BTW I'm using zsh.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.  Try https://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Droppy maybe we can try to leave questions about iTerm2 alone, as to solve this problem, may require you to look into the source code of iTerm2, which is related to programming :)

Comment: @sel-fish By that regard, any configuration issue with any program, where the source code is available, should be posted on stack overflow?  So issues with Blender or Unreal Engine or Gimp are OK here?

Comment: @Droppy :) you're right about that, but I think you're switching the question here. I agree with you about what you mentioned, but I just want to talk about iTerm, we move question just because if we do so,  it can draw more attention from the right place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an *zsh* binding is not an *iTerm* binding. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is the default binding for the `clear-screen` widget in zsh. The fact that it also works in *bash* (and maybe other shells) is merely convention. In *bash* - or rather *readline*, *bash's* command line editor - it is the default binding for a command that is also named `clear-screen`.

Generally, you can change a key binding in *zsh* with the command `bindkey KEYSEQUENCE WIDGET`. Unfortunately not all modifiers might be supported by *iTerm2* for use with the shell. You can test, whether it is supported by running `cat -v` and then pressing the desired key combination. If <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is supported, than the output shown should be more than just "`l`". If it something more or other than just "`l`", then you can use the output to bind it. For example if `cat -v` shows "`^[l`" than you can bind it with `bindkey '^[l' clear-screen` and if you want to remove the default binding, you can do so with `bindkey -r '^l'`.

Comment: Unfortunately the `Cmd+l` is not supported as tested with the method you described.

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl-L` or "form feed" is part of the ANSI/VT100 protocol (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes), it's not specific to iTerm2.

Your best best is to use Applescript to send Ctrl-L to the terminal when Cmd-L is pressed.