# Applescript to change shortcut to be able to clear lines in iTerm2

Tags: applescript, iterm2

I am trying to make an applescript to be able to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear lines in iTerm as suggested by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38264633/9930751).

After copying a working, example applescript from [here](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) shown below,

`tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using control down`

I am trying to change the application to "iTerm2" as shown below,

`tell application "iTerm2" to keystroke "l" using control down`

so the shortcut in not global, but I get a **Syntax error:**

> A identifier can’t go after this “"”.

Removing the quotes (*this also works in the working example*) brings up a different **Syntax error:**

> "A identifier can’t go after this identifier."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: iTerm has no method called `keystroke`. You would have to `activate` iTerm and then `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "l" using control down`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @gurkensaas's comment for the correct answer. I post the complete working script below for other people.

```
tell application "iTerm" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    try
        keystroke "l" using control down
    end try
end tell
```

Edit: I ended up using Better Touch Tool for this shortcut since it was much more responsive and fast.